# How do I use ChangeNotifier?

Tags: flutter, dart

From the docs I understood that one can call `addListener()` on a [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) instance to add a custom listener to the stack.

This method accepts a callback with zero arguments (according to [notifyListeners()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/notifyListeners.html)), e.g.:

```dart
class MyClass extends ChangeNotifier {

  MyClass() {
    addListener(() {
      // ...
    });
  }
}
```

From within the callback, how does one find out what properties or parts of `MyClass` have been changed?

Answer (score 13):

`ChangeNotifier` does not have such capabilities inherently. You will have to implement your own logic. Specifically, you either have access to all of the properties of your `ChangeNotifier` implementation because you add the listener in its scope or you have access to it because you have a reference to it in your scope.

[`ChangeNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) simply implements [`Listenable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Listenable-class.html) and provides some utilities for managing listeners. Furthermore, the documentation states the following about it:

> [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) is optimized for small numbers (one or two) of listeners. It is O(N) for adding and removing listeners and O(N²) for dispatching notifications (where N is the number of listeners).

I am not sure about options with better runtime complexity for notifying listeners, but you will not run into any issues in a regular Flutter app.

### ValueNotifier

[`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) is a pre-made implementation of `ChangeNotifier` that will notify its listeners when its [`value` property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier/value.html) is changed.
This is sufficient for most case, but since it appears that you want to create a custom `ChangeNotifier`, you can use the [source code of `ValueNotifier`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3c521fb980104d7e1b5488fcf9dc8b37fd282be6/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L257) to take a look at an example implementation (it is very straight forward).

---

If you are just looking to do state management in general, `ValueNotifier`s usually work great. However, they are not applicable in every scenario. Hence, here is an [extensive list with different state management options](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options).
Considering the questions, I think the techniques that fit your needs best and the most popular options are the following:

- [InheritedWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) as it lets you notify dependents based on what data changed. Additionally, there is [InheritedModel](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedModel-class.html) as an extension of this and [InheritedNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedModel-class.html) that works with [`Listenable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Listenable-class.html), just like `ChangeNotifier` does.
- The [BLOC](https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1) pattern, which works with streams.
- The [`provider` package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) which is mostly a convenience wrapper for various Flutter state management techniques (`InheritedWidget`, `StatefulWidget`, `ValueNotifier`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. It seems like ValueNotifier always notifies listeners when a new value is set, regardless if the new value is same as the previous value. Comparing current and new value and not rebuilding the widget tree if the values are the same is a sort of magic I was looking for

Comment: @Kaspi It will not rebuild if the values are the same. See [this line from the source code I linked to in my answer](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3c521fb980104d7e1b5488fcf9dc8b37fd282be6/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L270).